# How to generate a Rank r matrix with entries Uniform?

Tags: algorithms, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I want to generate a $200 \times 200$ matrix of low rank (say 5) with entries Uniformly distributed in [0,1]. What should be the right algorithm for this?

Comment: If $M$ is a random matrix with $M_{ij} \sim U(0, 1)$, then the determinant, being a linear combination of products of the $M_{ij}$, is a continuous random variable, in which case the probability it is equal to zero (as it must be, if $M$ is not full rank) is also zero, i.e. almost all random matrices will be invertible.

Comment: @Riley that entire argument is based on entries are independent which I do not want anyway. For example, if I wanted rank 1 matrix, I would have generated a vector u of entries e^{-gamma(1/2)}s and uu^T would have rank 1 and entries Uniform.

Comment: If the only constraint is that the entries are uniformly distributed, possibly not independently so, it seems one way would be to generate five vectors $v_1, \cdots, v_5$. The probability of any linear dependence is zero, so then you can just put the vectors in a matrix with repetition (i.e. 40 of each). But this doesn't seem like what you're after since it isn't a particularly interesting construction. (Although, instead of repetition, you can generate 200 vectors in the span of $\{v_1, \cdots, v_5\}$.)

Comment: It’s true that repetition works but I don’t want such specific case. Otherwise span idea doesn’t work because convex combination of uniforms are not uniform

Comment: Ah right, I forgot. In that case I can't think of any meaningful construction at this stage, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want entries to be "very random", since you already have considered using random linear span of random vectors and decided that it is not 'random' enough.  I write this since if you want this some practical reasons, I think that the solution above - using random vectors and linear span - will be somewhat nice, and much more efficient than solution I suggest.

The key is in singular value decomposition. Each eigenvalue is real and has single multiplicity, but you can slightly modify this if you need.

1) First, you generate a matrix $P$ of desired size, which must be orthogonal. For this, you can take various approach. http://home.lu.lv/~sd20008/papers/essays/Random%20unitary%20%5Bpaper%5D.pdf is a good reference, if you want to study this more. This pdf is for unitary matrices, and it suggests choosing random points from a sphere to assure uniform distribution.

2) pick $r$ random real numbers, which will be eigenvalue of your matrix. $D = diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_r, 0, \dots, 0)$.

3) Then, of course, use $A = PDP^{*}$.

This way, you can generate a matrix with given rank with uniform entries.